# Graph Api: Download file of a particular version in sharepoint

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, sharepoint-online

I can get the file metadata of a particular version:

```
/beta/sites/siteid/items/itemid/versions/versionid?expand=fields
```

I could not find an API to download the file of that version.

How can I download a file for a given version?

Answer (score 1):

Retrieving a previous version uses the same mechanism as [downloading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_get_content) the current file version. If you append `/content` to your URI it will retrieve the actual file rather than just it's metadata:

```
/beta/sites/{site-id}/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/versions/{version-id}/content
```

Comment: This is not working.  Getting BadRequest with message: Resource not found for the segment 'content

Comment: Try including `drives/{id}` -  `/beta/sites/{site-id}/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/versions/{version-id}/content`

Comment: I have tried several combinations, putting only drives and driveid,  including the one you suggested. But non is working. Not sure the rules are different to the sharepoint site created for msteam. I am doing these activities for site created for msteam

Comment: As long as versioning is enabled on the drive, it shouldn't matter where it came from. Teams create a SharePoint Team Site (technically I believe it's the Group that creates it but again, shouldn't really matter).  Are you able to retrieve a specific version via the SharePoint UI?

Comment: Yes I am able to retrieve specific version via the Sharepoint UI.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur how do you get the fields for a specific version?